# Can I map same domain with different path to different servers using DNS settings

Tags: dns

I have 2 different paths

Path 1. https://www.example.com

Path 2. https://www.example.com/app

example.com is generic website and example.com/app is a server where application is hosted
Currently both are hosted on same server.

Now I would like example.com to point to <server 1> in DNS and example.com/app to point to <server 2> using DNS settings.

Is it possible using DNS settings?